# What are some of the image classification datasets other than MNIST on which Deep Belief Network (DBN) has produced good results?

Tags: dataset, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

What are some of the image classification datasets other than MNIST on which Deep Belief Network (DBN) has produced state-of-the-art results? Even if its not state-of-the-art, but, I am looking for datasets on which DBN works without any pre-processing. For instance, for MNIST, without any pre-processing and feeding the raw images to the DBN, Hinton et al. have shown to obtain results of the order of 1.4% without dropout. I tried datasets like CIFAR-10, CIFAR-100 etc., but, the DBN won't converge. So, what are some of the image classification datasets other than MNIST on which DBN has been shown to work well or at least converge?

Comment: This question should remain open: it is not asking for a specific data set, but questions asking for examples from a specific class of data sets (i.e. *not* a specific data set) are permitted.